# HTTP response content parsing

Tags: php, http

im implementing tcp http post request in c++ using sdl_net.
the server side is php script that echo back.
im parsing the response content by splitting the data after "\r\n\r\n".
is this the right approach? im interested only in the line that the php echo back.
what is the "30" and the "0" in the response content?

this is the request:

```
INFO: POST /folder/file.php HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.website.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11

AA=aa&BB=bb
```

this is the response:

```
INFO: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 29 Dec 2018 16:46:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Via: 1.1 vegur

30
abc 123 ^|*. aa bbnextaaa bbnextbaanextcbbnextd.
0
```

this is the php script:

```
<?php
$AA = $_POST['AA'];
$BB = $_POST['BB'];


echo "abc 123 ^|*. $AA $BB";
echo "nexta";
echo "$AA $BB";
echo "nextb";
echo $AA;
echo "nextc";
echo $BB;
echo "nextd";
echo ".";
?>
```

Comment: The intersparsed length fields stem from `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. That's one of the pitfalls of implementing your own HTTP processor. Also, why?

Comment: the sdl_net library doesnt have an http parser int it, im open for any suggestions.
is there a way to get rid of the " intersparsed length fields stem from Transfer-Encoding: chunked" ? @mario

Comment: See also [avoiding chunked encoding of HTTP/1.1 response](//stackoverflow.com/q/18174435) or [How to avoid "chunked" Transfer-Encoding?](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/38738) or [How can I disable Transfer-Encoding: chunked in Apache with HTTP/1.1 responses](//serverfault.com/q/155558) // don't use HTTP/1.1 if you don't support it, ob_ buffering, or perhaps Accept-Encoding.